# Library search paths using the -R option

Tags: linker, g++

There are multitudes of articles online that proclaim in strident tones that the use of LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a bad idea, and that one must set library search paths using the -R option. The majority of said articles also mention Solaris in the same breath. The trouble is, on Linux, this does not work with g++.

```
g++: unrecognized option '-R'
```

Now what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-Wl,-rpath=/your/rpath`:

```
$ g++ -o t t.cpp -Wl,-rpath=/my/lib/dir -lwhatever
$ readelf -a t|grep RPATH
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/my/lib/dir]
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I just tried that, and realized the problem goes deeper. I want to build an application that I can ship out, and not have the end-user set runtime search paths. If I do it this way, then the whole thing only works when the built application is called from a specific location. The relative runtime search path is not valid from other directories. Naturally, I don't know what the absolute search path would be. The ideal thing would be to compile statically, but that seems to be an issue while linking against libstdc++. Thanks for the quick response.